# Trouble importing json file

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to use public json file as data source with following javascript:

```
const url = "https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/resource/ez6b-syvw.json";

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxConfig:{
        method: 'GET'
    },
    ajaxURL: url, //ajax URL
    index:"MessageID",
    autoResize:true,
    layout:"fitData", //layout options
    placeholder:"Awaiting Data...",
    columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"timestamp", field:"timestamp"},
        {title:"temperature", field:"temp_avg"},
        {title:"humidity", field:"humidity_avg"},
        {title:"latitude", field:"latitude"},
        {title:"longtitude", field:"longtitude"},

    ],

    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        //url - the URL of the request
        //params - the parameters passed with the request
        //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.

        return response; //pass the data array into Tabulator
    },

    rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
    alert("Row " + row.getData().MessageId + " Clicked!!!!");
    },
});
```

But I get following console message in chrome:

> Access to fetch at 'https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/resource/ez6b-syvw.json' from origin 'http://192.168.0.6' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
>   data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/resource/ez6b-syvw.json:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>   tabulator.min.js:5 Ajax Load Error - Connection Error:  TypeError: Failed to fetch
>   (anonymous) @ tabulator.min.js:5
>   tabulator.min.js:5 Ajax Load Error:  TypeError: Failed to fetch

I donot know what am I doing wrong?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at:http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/data#ajax-cors. What happens if you click on the link directly?

Comment: Thank you for your pointer. I now moved to local file on server to fetch data. I have a webserver on ESP32 but it produces json data in following format:

Comment: Thank you for your pointer. I now moved to local file on server to fetch data. I have a webserver on ESP32 but it produces json data file in following format: 

{"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":-82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"SleepTime":1,"UpTime":138}
{"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":-82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"SleepTime":1,"UpTime":138}

I tried it but format is not compatible with tabulator.Is there anything I can do to convert it to compatible format in tabulator.
Thanks.

Comment: If the data is an array of objects then it should be compatible as long as the field names in the Tabulator table match the object keys. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: tabulator.min.js:6 Ajax Load Error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 119
(anonymous) @ tabulator.min.js:6
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 236ms

Comment: {"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":-

82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"Sl

eepTime":1,"UpTime":138},
{"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":-

82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"Sl

eepTime":1,"UpTime":138},
{"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":-

82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"Sl

eepTime":1,"UpTime":138},
{"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":-

82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"Sl

eepTime":1,"UpTime":138},

Comment: tabulator.min.js:6 Ajax Load Error - Invalid JSON returned SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 119
(anonymous) @ tabulator.min.js:6
tabulator.min.js:6 Ajax Load Error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 119
(anonymous) @ tabulator.min.js:6
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 236ms

Comment: First keys in this JSON does match your table. Second as noted in comments to answer below the JSON has a rogue ','  at position 119.  Oh I see. You need to include the objects in an array, so: ```[{"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":- 82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"Sl eepTime":1,"UpTime":138}, {"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":- 82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"Sl eepTime":1,"UpTime":138}, {"Location":"Livingroom","SingnalStrength":- 82,"DeviceMode":0,"DeviceIP":26,"WiFiChannel":7,"Sl eepTime":1,"UpTime":138}]```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue getting the data from your resource.  Tabulator appears to always send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, but your resource does not allow this.  So, a workaround is to use your own `fetch` request instead of the `Tabulator` ajax options.  Then you can use `setData` on the table instance.

Here is an example.  https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/8wd3zo9q/33/

I am not sure if this is a bug, or if I am just not seeing a way to do it.

Comment: Yes that worked for external data file. Thank you but I still have to solve local file problem.I have provided error messages in earlier comments.

Comment: I tried your solution for local file source but get following in Chrome console:

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 105
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ index1.htm:122

getData().then((data) => {        //above reference to this line.

Comment: That just means your data is not valid JSON, so something happened when moving it to a local source.  From the error, it looks like there is a `,` at character position 105 and it is not expecting a comma there.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your ajaxConfig and you are good to go.

ajaxConfig:{
mode: "no-cors",
method: 'GET'
}